# Playwright Error: Firefox revision is not downloaded. Run "npm install" or "yarn install"

Tags: javascript, playwright

```
const playwright = require("playwright");

(async () => {
  const browsers = ["chromium", "firefox", "webkit"];

  for (const browserType of browsers) {
    const browser = await playwright[browserType].launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage("http://whatsmyuseragent.org/");

    await page.screenshot({ path: `example-${browserType}.png` });
  }
})();
```

after running this script, I got

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Firefox revision is not 
downloaded. Run "npm install" or "yarn install" in the console.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using npm in place of yarn the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Playwright CLI to install the browsers:

```
npx playwright install
```

The reason that the revisions can't be found is mostly due that NPM's cache is not configured properly when `node_modules` are e.g. cached on some CI environment. Since NPM thinks Playwright is installed but the actual browsers are stored in another location. See [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/cli#install-system-dependencies) for reference.